# Bootstrap / JQuery Invalid XML Parser Error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to bind Bootstrap form buttons to JQuery functions. The plain HTML works absolutely fine, but on the Bootstrap version the JQuery is throwing an 'invalid xml message' error 'onclick'. I've validated the HTML file and all looks fine there. You will see from code that I'm using onclick="" in HTML, to bind the buttons to JQuery. This is how I've written the bindings for the plain HTML/JQuery, and would like to preserve that if possible.

I've attached both versions of HTML and my JQuery code, as well as a transcript of the error message.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance...

**HTML without Bootstrap (all JQuery "onclick=" bindings work)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FilmDB Application</title>

    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script
            src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#20b2aa">
    <tr><th><big></big>Film Search Application</th></tr>
</table>

<br><label>Base Webservice URL: <input type="text" id="restwebservice"
                                value="http://localhost:8080/Section8_WS_ReST_war_exploded/FilmRESTWebservice"/></label><br><br>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Get All Films</legend>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="button" value="XML" onclick="getAllFilms(
            'restwebservice', 'getallfilms', 'xml')"/>

        <input type="button" value="JSON" onclick="getAllFilms(
            'restwebservice', 'getallfilms', 'json')"/>

        <input type="button" value="TEXT" onclick="getAllFilms(
            'restwebservice', 'getallfilms', 'text')"/>
    </form>
    <p/>
    <div id="getallfilms"></div>
</fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Get Films By Name</legend>
    <form action="#">
        <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="filmname"/></label><br></br>
        <input type="button" value="XML"
               onclick="getFilmsByName('restwebservice', 'getfilmsbyname', 'xml', 'filmname')"/>
        <input type="button" value="JSON"
               onclick="getFilmsByName('restwebservice', 'getfilmsbyname', 'json', 'filmname')"/>
        <input type="button" value="TEXT"
               onclick="getFilmsByName('restwebservice', 'getfilmsbyname', 'text', 'filmname')"/>
    </form>
    <p/>
    <div id="getfilmsbyname"></div>
</fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Get Film By ID</legend>
    <form action="#">
        <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="filmid"/></label><br></br>
        <input type="button" value="XML"
               onclick="getFilmById('restwebservice', 'getfilmbyid', 'xml', 'filmid')"/>
        <input type="button" value="JSON"
               onclick="getFilmById('restwebservice', 'getfilmbyid', 'json', 'filmid')"/>
        <input type="button" value="TEXT"
               onclick="getFilmById('restwebservice', 'getfilmbyid', 'text', 'filmid')"/>
    </form>
</fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Update Film Details</legend>
    <form action="#">

        <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="u_filmid" readonly/></label><br></br>
        <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="u_filmname"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Year: <input type="text" id="u_year"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Director: <input type="text" id="u_director"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Cast: <input type="text" id="u_stars"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Plot: <input type="text" id="u_review"/></label><br></br>

        <input type="button" value="XML"
               onclick="updateFilm(
                       'u_filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'xml')"/>
        <input type="button" value="JSON"
               onclick="updateFilm(
                       'u_filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'json')"/>
        <input type="button" value="TEXT"
               onclick="updateFilm(
                       'u_filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'text')"/><br></br>

    </form>
    <div id="updatefilm"></div>
</fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add New Film</legend>
    <form action="#">

        <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="add_filmname"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Year: <input type="text" id="add_year"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Director: <input type="text" id="add_director"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Cast: <input type="text" id="add_stars"/></label><br></br>
        <label>Plot: <input type="text" id="add_review"/></label><br></br>

        <input type="button" value="XML"
               onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'xml')"/>

        <input type="button" value="JSON"
               onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'json')"/>

        <input type="button" value="TEXT"
               onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'restwebservice', 'text')"/>
    </form>
</fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Delete Film</legend>
    <form action="#">
        <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="deletefilmid"/></label><br></br>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Film"
               onclick="deleteFilm('deletefilmid', 'restwebservice')"/>
    </form>
    <div id="deletefilm"></div>
</fieldset><br></br>

<!-- add single div id for table results -->
<div id="filmtable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML with Bootstrap (binding only included for 'Get All Films')**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Film DB Application</title>

  <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-md">
  <section class="content mt-4" id="filmdbapp">
    <!-- can now call variable-->
    <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">
      <strong>FILM DATABASE APPLICATION</strong></h3>
  </section>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-3">
        <p>### STATIC ###</p>
        <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">Web Service URL (edit default if required)</h3>

        <input class="form-control mt-3 mb-3" type="text" id="restwebservice"
               placeholder="http://localhost:8080/Section8_WS_ReST_war_exploded/FilmRESTWebservice">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"
                onclick="getAllFilms('restwebservice', 'getallfilms', 'xml')">Get All Films</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add New Film</button>

      </div><!-- button group -->
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">Search Request</h3>
    <input class="form-control mt-3 mb-3" type="text" id="searchinfo"
           placeholder="Enter film name or ID here">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="jsonRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="jsonRadio">JSON</label>

      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="xmlRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="xmlRadio">XML</label>

      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="textRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="textRadio">Text</label>
    </div><!-- form check -->

    <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By Name</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By ID</button>
    </div><!-- button group -->
  </div>
</div><br>

<div class="container-md">
  <p>### DYNAMIC ###<br>Displayed when user clicks either of the three 'Get' search buttons</p>

  <div id="filmtable"></div>

  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <!-- still struggling with this - might need to stick with 6 column table-->
      <div class="table-active mb-3">
        <table class="table">
          <thead><tr><th scope="col">FILM SEARCH RESULTS</th></tr></thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr><th scope="row">Film Name</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Year</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Main Cast</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Director</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Plot</th></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div><!-- table class -->
      <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </div><!-- button group -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <p>### DYNAMIC ###<br>Displayed when user clicks 'Add Film' button</p>
        <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">Add Film Details</h3>
        <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="filmName"
               placeholder="Film name">
        <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="year"
               placeholder="Year">
        <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="cast"
                  rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
        <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="director"
               placeholder="Director">
        <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="plot"
                  rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add Film</button>
      </div><br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <p>### DYNAMIC ###<br>Displayed when user clicks 'Update' button from search results</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">Update Film Details</h3>
          <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="u_filmName"
                 placeholder="Film name">
          <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="u_year"
                 placeholder="Year">
          <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="u_cast"
                    rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
          <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="u_director"
                 placeholder="Director">
          <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="u_plot"
                    rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Film</button>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div><!-- container -->
<script src="resources/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery Code (Get All Films only)**

```
function getAllFilms(servletAddress, action, dataFormat) {

    $.ajax({

        url: document.getElementById(servletAddress).value,     
        type: "GET",
        dataType : dataFormat,                                  
        data : {action : action,
                format : dataFormat},                           
        success: function(servletResponse) {                    
            tableResponseHandler(servletResponse, dataFormat, servletAddress);   
        },

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

**Web Service Servlet Code (just added doGet)**

```
@WebServlet(name = "FilmRESTWebservice", value = "/FilmRESTWebservice")
public class FilmRESTWebservice extends HttpServlet {

    Output output = new Output();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        FilmDAO filmDAO = FilmDAO.getInstance();
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        ArrayList<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<>();

        String action = "";
        String dataFormat = "";
        int filmId = -1;
        String filmName = "";

        // sets 'get' method to call, i.e. getall, getbyid or getbyname
        if (request.getParameter("action") != null) {
            action = request.getParameter("action");
        }

        // add logic for handling request parameters
        if (request.getParameter("format") != null) {                   
            dataFormat = request.getParameter("format");
        }

        if (request.getParameter("id") != null) {                      
            filmId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        }

        if (request.getParameter("filmName") != null) {                 
            filmName = request.getParameter("filmName");
        }

        // add logic for handling GET request type
        if (action.equals("getallfilms")) {
            filmList = filmDAO.getAllFilms();

        } else if (action.equals("getfilmbyid")) {
            filmList.add(filmDAO.getFilmById(filmId));

        } else if (action.equals("getfilmsbyname")) {
            filmList = filmDAO.getFilmByName(filmName);
        }

        // add logic for handling data format
        if (dataFormat.equals("json")) {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            String jsonResult = gson.toJson(filmList);

            jsonResult = "{\"films\":" + jsonResult + "}"; 
            printWriter.write(jsonResult);
        }

        else if (dataFormat.equals("xml")) {
            try {
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                printWriter.write(output.xmlToStringGenerator(filmList));
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (dataFormat.equals("text")) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            printWriter.write(output.stringGenerator(filmList));
        }

        else {
            printWriter.write("Data format unsupported");
        }
    }
```

**Transcript of Error Message (thrown by JQuery function, displayed in alert box)**

```
Error: Error: Invalid XML:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Film DB Application</title>

  <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-md">
  <section class="content mt-4" id="filmdbapp">
    <!-- can now call variable-->
    <h3 style="color: darkslateblue">
      <strong>FILM DATABASE APPLICATION</strong></h3>
  </section>
  <form>
...
```

Comment: Your onclick says you are expecting xml but that is html being returned by that request. Either have your URL's wrong or have a back end problem or you want html not xml

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. The ‘xml’ value in the html on click is just a text value passed into the Ajax function, to tell the back end web service to return the response as xml. You will see the non-bootstrap version does the same thing (as well as json and plain text)

Comment: Right I understand that but the response with your error shows html, not xml. So when jQuery tries to parse as xml document it can't

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Still not quite sure I understand. The JQuery isn't trying to parse the HTML document. It just makes an Ajax request to the web service servlet, passing the url and additional search attributes (action and format). The web service handles the fetch and parsing, which it dumps into a div on the web page. I've added the doGet code from my web service servlet

Comment: Yes it is. When you set `dataType:'xml'` it uses [parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to turn it into an [XML Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML#creating_an_xml_document). If it's not valid XML it fires the $.ajax error handler and that is exactly what you are seeing

Comment: problem solved @charlietfl. the Ajax code uses document.getElementById(servletAddress).value to fetch the servlet address. the input class for 'restwebservice' used 'placeholder'. just needed changing to 'value'. i've actually decided to ditch using bootstrap. all my code has been written using html/jquery, and it seems that bootstrap doesn't play very nicely with it, without a fair bit of refactoring. just going to stick with basic css styling instead. thanks for your help